# Android: Configuration Change Not Updating

Tags: android, user-interface, orientation, emulation, config

I am using the XML tag

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
```

and the following code to detect device orientation changes and change layouts:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    disp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    swidth = disp.getWidth();
    sheight = disp.getHeight();
    parent.removeAllViews();
    parent = new RelativeLayout(this);
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        layoutPortrait();
    else
        layoutLandscape();
}
```

This works fine going form portrait to landscape.  But, for whatever reason, going from landscape to portrait (starting in landscape or switching to it then back) doesn't change the screen back to portrait.

Through the use of Log messages I've determined that after being in Landscape mode, the Display and Configuration classes DO NOT UPDATE.  They remain holding the same orientation/length/width values as when the device was in landscape.

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

**Additional Code (requested by contributor)**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    disp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    swidth = disp.getWidth();
    sheight = disp.getHeight();
    int ornt;
    if(swidth == sheight)
        ornt = Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE;
    else if(swidth < sheight)
        ornt = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    else if(swidth > sheight)
        ornt = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    else
        ornt = Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
    parent = new RelativeLayout(this);
    labelOne = new TextView(this);
    labelOne.setText("Temperature");
    labelOne.setId((int)(Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    temp = new EditText(this);
    temp.setSingleLine(true);
    temp.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    temp.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    temp.setId((int)(Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    labelTwo = new TextView(this);
    labelTwo.setText("Humidity(%)");
    labelTwo.setId((int)(Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    humidity = new EditText(this);
    humidity.setSingleLine(true);
    humidity.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    humidity.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    humidity.setId((int)(Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    output = new TextView(this);
    output.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    output.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    output.setId((int)(Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    submit = new Button(this);
    submit.setText("Calculate");
    submit.setId((int)(Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              Double result = Calculate.calculate(getInputs());
              if(result !=null) {
                String answer = String.format("%,.1f",result);
                if(f.isChecked()) {
                    output.setText(answer + "°F");
                } else {
                    output.setText(answer + "°C");
                }
              }
        }
    });
    f = new RadioButton(this);
    f.setText("Fahrenheit");
    c = new RadioButton(this);
    c.setText("Celsius");
    rg = new RadioGroup(this);
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new ListenForMode());
    rg.addView(f);
    rg.addView(c);
    rg.setId((int)(Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    f.setChecked(true);
    if(ornt == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT || ornt == Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE)
        layoutPortrait();
    else
        layoutLandscape();
}
```

**Final Update**

Issue is with the emulator not responding correctly to the orientation changes.  I changed the onConfigurationChanged(...) orientation checking to use the condition width < height for portrait and all else landscape.  This works perfectly on my Android device.

Thanks to all contributors to this question!

Comment: Why not just let Android handle the switching of layouts for you by providing alternate resources?

Comment: Second that. Also, is your layoutLandScape routine calling setRequestedOrientation, by any chance? Once you do this, you will stop getting notifications of orientation changes.

Comment: @LawrenceD'Oliveiro Not it does not call that method.  It just repaints the layout to work with a landscape view.

Comment: You have no fall back call to one of your layouts. You should refactor the `if else if` to a `if else`. Check for portrait, if not, do landscape ignore the rest... (will not solve your issue, but should be more robust)

Comment: @bschultz By alternate resources do you mean BMP GUI layouts?  I don't know how to make those, and I would rather just write as much of my programs as possible in pure Java since that is what I know and love.

Comment: Could you provide a complete minimal app project that one can use to reproduce the problem with please? I can't reproduce the problem with the code you show. In particular, I am interested in your Activity.onCreate() and how you initialize 'parent', but the more code the merrier.

Comment: @MartinNordholts Updated with the requested information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it happens on emulator, then it's OK - emulator behaves a little bit weird in sense of configuration changes. I have been trying to solve similar problem, unless I noticed that the app worked fine on a real device.

It seems that the emulator ignores the `android:configChanges="orientation"` attribute, but in a bit strange way: it does force the configuration change but doesn't call `onConfigurationChanged(..)` method every time it should be called.

Comment: It doesn't do anything on emulator.  Did I mention that it crashes on the actual phone?

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be overriding the configChanges in your manifest. Android can handle redrawing the Views for you, and it actually handles it really well, especially if you have filtered layouts in your resource folder.

If you are overriding configChanges because of issues with AsyncTask losing its Context (as I once did), I would recommend using an IntentService to handle your asynchronous work as Services aren't tied to any one Activity.

Comment: But don't I have to override it if I want it to use a different layout?  Remember I'm doing this in Java code NOT using BMP resources.

Comment: If you put your landscape layout in layout-land and keep the names the same Android will pick the layout in the layout-land

Comment: Are you saying that you're building your layouts in Java code and not XML?